# Change TagLib tag depending on string

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

I'm working on an audio tagger and one of its features is basically detecting if the checkbox with the tag name is checked and if the value in the textbox is changed.

This is the code I used so far:

```cs
if (chbAlbum.Checked == true && tbAlbum.Text != musFileTag.Album) { 
    fileStatus(3);
    tsbCloseFile.Enabled = false; 
} 
else {
    fileStatus(2); 
    tsbCloseFile.Enabled = true; 
}
```

now I'm switching to custom void:

```cs
void Checker(CheckBox chBox, TextBox tBox, String stringTag) {
    var musFileTag = TagLib.File.Create(musFileName).Tag;
    if (chBox.Checked == true && tBox.Text != musFileTag) { 
        return;
    }
}
```

how can I determine what tag it will be using from a string?

Normally to get an album tag I would use `musFileTag.Album` and for artist `musFileTag.Performers` but I need to determine the tag type from the string (something like `musFileTag.{stringTag}`)

Comment: _how can I specify what tag it will be using from a string?_ - can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used a switch:

```cs
Boolean Checker(String stringTag) {
       var musFileTag = TagLib.File.Create(musFileName).Tag;
       bool returningValue = false;

       switch (stringTag)
       {
           case "album":
               if(chbAlbum.Checked == true && tbAlbum.Text != musFileTag.Album) {returningValue = true; }
               break;
       }
}
```